# What are the conditions in naming the xml layout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

When we are giving name to the `xml` file in the layout folder of the **android** project what all we have to take into consideration.

Answer (score 2):

```
   File name must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or _.
```

- only `a-z`,mind that not capital...and `white-space not allowed`
- name must start with a character.
- name only `_` symbol allowed